# PHP: scan directory, compress & overwrite images - script fails on production, produces just warnings on local

Tags: php, image, gd, cron-task, image-compression

I have this code that is run as a cron task. Basically what it does (should) is go through a folder, find images that are larger than the specified size, rezise them and overwrite them.

When testing it locally (using same 1300+ images) it works. If I remove the **@** error supressant on **imagecreatefromjpeg** and **imagecreatefrom_png** I get the following warnings:

```
    Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: 
    Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG in 
    C:\xampp56\htdocs\svamz\static\uploaded\image_compress.php on line 70

    Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): './certificate/POCAJT4.jpg' is not a 
    valid JPEG file in 
    C:\xampp56\htdocs\svamz\static\uploaded\image_compress.php on line 70
   POCAJT4.jpg resize Failed!
```

This warning is output for some images, but mostly the images are compressed and these images with warnings are skipped.

The problem is that on a server (*Apache2, PHP 5.6.40*) the execution of the same code produces just a 500 HTTP error. No errors, no warnings (that's making this a pain in the ass to debug)

Source/Target directories are writable. I have also tested the code by changing  the if statement to include only a portion of images by using **filesize($imagePath) > 8000000 && filesize($imagePath) < 9000000** and that works fine on the server. But as soon I try a range of filesize that contains these problematic images it breaks back to 500.

I tried to get to the problem with **try** **catch**, I also used **set_error_handler()** to try and catch ***E_WARNING*** messages on server but with no results.

*gd_info()* is the same locally and on server.

I think it is unrelated but *php -v* (also error.log) along with it's normal output gives this:
***Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ZendGuardLoader5.6.so:  /usr/local/lib/ZendGuardLoader5.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory***

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

$imagesDirectory = './certificate/'; //Source directory
$destinationDirectory = './certificate/'; //Destination directory
$newImageWidth = 1600;
$newImageHeight = 1200;
$quality = 80;

// Source image directory, loop through each Image and resize it.
if($dir = opendir($imagesDirectory)){        
    while(($file = readdir($dir))!== false){
        $imagePath = $imagesDirectory.$file;
        $destPath = $destinationDirectory.$file;
        $checkValidImage = @getimagesize($imagePath);
        //image exists, is valid & larger than X
        if(file_exists($imagePath) && $checkValidImage && filesize($imagePath) > 800000)
        {      
                // resize
                if(resizeImage($imagePath,$destPath,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$quality))
                {                                        
                    echo $file.' resized<br>';                    
                } else{
                    echo $file.' resize Failed!<br>';
                }                
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
}
//Function that resizes image.
function resizeImage($srcImage,$destImage, $maxWidth,$maxHeight,$quality)
{

// Get dimensions of source image.
list($origWidth, $origHeight, $type) = getimagesize($srcImage);

if ($maxWidth == 0) {
    $maxWidth  = $origWidth;
}

if ($maxHeight == 0) {
    $maxHeight = $origHeight;
}

// Calculate ratio of desired maximum sizes and original sizes.
$widthRatio = $maxWidth / $origWidth;
$heightRatio = $maxHeight / $origHeight;

// Ratio used for calculating new image dimensions.
$ratio = min($widthRatio, $heightRatio);

// Calculate new image dimensions.
$newWidth  = (int)$origWidth  * $ratio;
$newHeight = (int)$origHeight * $ratio;

$newCanvas = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

switch(strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type($type)))
{
    case 'image/jpeg':                      
        $newImage = @imagecreatefromjpeg($srcImage);

        if (!$newImage) {
            return false;
        }

    // copy file
    if(imagejpeg($newCanvas,$destImage,$quality)) {
        imagedestroy($newCanvas);
        return true;
    }            
    break;

    case 'image/png':
        $newImage = @imagecreatefrompng($srcImage);

        if (!$newImage) {
            return false;
        }

        // copy file
        if(imagepng($newCanvas,$destImage, floor($quality / 10))) {
            imagedestroy($newCanvas);
            return true;
        }             
    break;

    default:
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        // Resize Image
        imagecopyresampled($newCanvas, $newImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $origWidth, $origHeight);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        print $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }    
}
```

The goal is to compress & overwrite if it's possible and skip if it's not. I have no control over what images the end users are uploading.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Configure PHP to write errors to a log file, and then check what that has to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@misorude Could not do that at this time because the person with write permissions is away at this time.

Turn out setting just *ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);* is not enough.

This worked for me:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**The error was out of memory.**